# Aggregate duplicate rows in one along with their counts

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe that looks something like this:

```
    status      id  lat         lon
0   Active      1   55.233423   11.763270
1   Inactive    2   57.042838   9.950013
2   Inactive    2   57.042838   9.950013
3   Inactive    3   56.138585   9.153843
4   Active      4   55.633564   12.017864
5   Active      5   56.982541   9.638719
6   Active      6   55.564366   9.757486
7   Active      7   57.167606   10.147661
8   Active      8   56.762328   8.866716
9   Active      9   56.715710   10.113781
```

What I want is to club records by `id` column and add the count of occurrences for each id in a new column `count`.

Such that there would be one row for each id and the count of total record that were previously there in the column `count` next to it.

```
    status      id  lat         lon         count
0   Active      1   55.233423   11.763270
1   Inactive    2   57.042838   9.950013    2
2   Inactive    3   56.138585   9.153843
3   Active      4   55.633564   12.017864
4   Active      5   56.982541   9.638719
5   Active      6   55.564366   9.757486
6   Active      7   57.167606   10.147661
7   Active      8   56.762328   8.866716
8   Active      9   56.715710   10.113781
```

A part of it I succeeded in achieving it through:

```
grouped = df.groupby('id').agg(np.mean)
grouped.head()
```

But I am still unable to figure out how to put `counts` in the new column and it also removes the `status` column from the resulting df.

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `size`

```
g = df.groupby(['id','status'])

out = g.mean().join(g.size().to_frame('cnt')).reset_index()
Out[54]: 
   id    status        lat        lon  cnt
0   1    Active  55.233423  11.763270    1
1   2  Inactive  57.042838   9.950013    2
2   3  Inactive  56.138585   9.153843    1
3   4    Active  55.633564  12.017864    1
4   5    Active  56.982541   9.638719    1
5   6    Active  55.564366   9.757486    1
6   7    Active  57.167606  10.147661    1
7   8    Active  56.762328   8.866716    1
8   9    Active  56.715710  10.113781    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Groupby.agg`:

```
In [1214]: df.groupby(['id', 'status']).agg([np.mean, 'count'])
Out[1214]: 
                   lat              lon      
                  mean count       mean count
id status                                    
1  Active    55.233423     1  11.763270     1
2  Inactive  57.042838     2   9.950013     2
3  Inactive  56.138585     1   9.153843     1
4  Active    55.633564     1  12.017864     1
5  Active    56.982541     1   9.638719     1
6  Active    55.564366     1   9.757486     1
7  Active    57.167606     1  10.147661     1
8  Active    56.762328     1   8.866716     1
9  Active    56.715710     1  10.113781     1
```